# Make a component with different sizes using SASS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I was always wondering how to make component with different sizes using SASS in React.

[image]

These are from airbnb, and let's assume these are same components.

The first one is 520px and the second one is around 130px.
If there exist these two sizes only, I know I can adjust the size using different `className`.

But what if I need different sizes more than two? like 300px, 400px and etc? Is it the only way to set `className` every time?

I could pass `style` prop to component, but it's CSS in JS so I think it becomes meaningless to use SASS.

How do others work with SASS in this kind of situation? I can't shift to Styled component now.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with dynamic `className` and a prop `size`. Something like this:

```
const Button = ({ size, ... }) => {
  [...]
  return (
    <button className={`button-${size}`}>
      [...]
    </button>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "small",
    "regular",
    "large",
  ]),
  ...
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  size: "regular"
};
```

In you styles:

```
$buttonSizes: (
   small: 300px,
   regular: 400px,
   large: 500px,
);

button {
   @each $sizeName, $size in $buttonSizes {
     &-#{$sizeName} {
       width: $size;
     }
   }
}
```